# How to check if Google Street View available and display message?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-street-view

I am passing lat and lng variables and display google sreet view in a div. The problem is that when the StreetView is unavilable then nothing is displayed. I would like to check if there is a streetview for a given lat and lng and display a message. Here is my code:

```
var myPano = new GStreetviewPanorama(document.getElementById("street2"), panoOpts);
var location = new GLatLng(lat,lng)
myPano.setLocationAndPOV(location);
```

Maybe I should use something like:  `Event.addListener(myPano, "error", errorMessage());`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In v3 this has changed a bit. Check out the documentation at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#StreetViewService

The updated code is:

```
var streetViewService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
var STREETVIEW_MAX_DISTANCE = 100;
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.7140, -74.0062);
streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(latLng, STREETVIEW_MAX_DISTANCE, function (streetViewPanoramaData, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
        // ok
    } else {
        // no street view available in this range, or some error occurred
    }
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `getPanoramaByLocation` is asynchronous. Meaning anything you want to do as a result of the check has to go into the call back function.

Answer (score 17):

You may want to check out the following reference:

- [Google Maps API Documentation: Street View Client Querying](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#StreetviewClientQuerys)

> Determining whether a road supports Street View by visual inspection of the `GStreetviewOverlay` is not often feasible, or desirable from a user's perspective. For that reason, the API provides a service which programmatically requests and retrieves Street View data. This service is facilitated through use of the `GStreetviewClient` object.

Basically you can use the [`getNearestPanoramaLatLng()`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GStreetviewClient.getNearestPanoramaLatLng) method of the [`GStreetviewClient`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GStreetviewClient) class, which will return you a [`GLatLng`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GLatLng) of the nearest point where street view is available. You can then use the [`distanceFrom()`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GLatLng.distanceFrom) method to check if the nearest street view point is within a certain threshold from your source point.

Here is a full example, which I believe should be self explanatory:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <title>Google Maps API - Street View Availability</title> 
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
       var testPoint = new GLatLng(40.7140, -74.0062);   // Broadway, New York
       var svClient = new GStreetviewClient();

       svClient.getNearestPanoramaLatLng(testPoint, function (nearest) {
          if ((nearest !== null) && (testPoint.distanceFrom(nearest) <= 100)) {
             alert('Street View Available');             // Within 100 meters
          }
          else {
             alert('Street View Noet Available');        // Not within 100 meters
          }
       });
    </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: This answer is outdated. See the V3 answer [and docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#StreetViewService)

Answer (score 2):

Update for Google Maps JavaScript API v3.25+:
In v3.25 (current release version) and v3.26 (current experimental version), `getPanoramaByLocation()` is still available but [not documented anymore](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#StreetViewService).

@arthur-clemens's accepted answer still works, but use `getPanorama()` with a `StreetViewLocationRequest` instead if you want better compatibility:

```
var gstService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();

gstService.getPanorama({
    location: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7140, -74.0062),
    source: google.maps.StreetViewSource.OUTDOOR
}, function (data, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
        // OK
    } else {
        // error or no results
    }
});
```

Omit `source` in the `StreetViewLocationRequest` if you do not want the panorama search to be limited to outdoor ones.