# Google Maps: Is there a way to find out whether a city has a detailed map (not StreetView)?

Tags: google-maps

I have a point on a map. The point belongs to a city which doesn't have a detailed view with all the streets and buildings yet. But I hope Google will cover this city some time in the future. So I have to display map in a satellite view for now but it would be perfect if the map started to display in a standard view as soon as Google covers the city.

Is it possible to determine programmatically whether city has a detailed view with streets and buildings on Google Maps?

Comment: Possible dupe of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2675032/1314132

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I didn't mean "street view", I meant "detailed view of a city with streets and buildings" in a map view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem using reverse geocoding for a given point on a map. If result has a `ROOFTOP` `location_type` parameter, that means that the map contains a building at that point. Otherwise there are no buildings.