# Only show google street view when available

Tags: jquery, api, google-maps, maps

I have a dynamic page that pulls different locations depending on the ID. I have three tabs one for the location description, google maps and one for the street view. Everything works - the problem I'm having is when there isn't street view available it shows a grey box.

I thought I found a solution by using 'getPanoramaByLocation' but I can't seem to make it work correctly. This is what I have:

```
var WINDOW_HTML = '<div style="width: 200px; overflow: hidden; word-wrap:break-word;"><p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($title); ?><br /><?php echo htmlspecialchars($locationDetails); ?></p></div>';
    var map = '';
    var myLatlng;

    /* Check if Streetview is available */
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo htmlspecialchars($lat.','.$lon); ?>);                      

    var streetViewCheck = new google.maps.StreetViewService();  
    streetViewCheck.getPanoramaByLocation(latLng, 50, function(result, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                streetViewAvailable = 0;        
            } else {
                streetViewAvailable = 1;
            }
    });        

    function initialize() {                 
        myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo htmlspecialchars($lat.','.$lon); ?>);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('themap'), mapOptions);

        /* Street view addition */                   
        if (streetViewAvailable == 1) {                
            var panoramaOptions = {
            position: myLatlng,
            pov: {
              heading: 34,
              pitch: 10
            },
            visible:true
            };
             var panorama = new  google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'),panoramaOptions);                     
            map.setStreetView(panorama);
            alert('Street View Available'); 
        } else {  
            /* Hide the street view tab if it isn't available */
            $('#svTab').hide(); 
            alert('Street View NOT Available');                
        }           

        /* Resize Fix for tabs */
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'resize', function() {
            this.setZoom(13);
            this.setCenter(myLatlng);
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: WINDOW_HTML
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map
            });            
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });                
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        }); 
        // Tab fix for streetview refresh  
          $('#svTab').on('shown', function (e) {
            $('#pano').show();                   
            panorama.setVisible(true);  

        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I've tried lots of different things and I seem to get varying results - one setup I had seemed to be working, but when I refreshed the page  for some unknown reason it would then say my 'streetViewAvailable' wasn't defined (it was as if it wasn't running through my streetViewCheck function).

Comment: Perhaps try declaring streetViewAvailable globally and defaulting it to 0?

Comment: See previous answer here for a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675032/how-to-check-if-google-street-view-available-and-display-message

Comment: Hi Swires, I tried setting the streetViewAvailable default to 0 but then that strange bug occurs where once I change the page ID in the url it defaults to 0. It's as if it doesn't run through the streetViewCheck for some unknown reason. I'll try swapping out my function with that other link though and see if I get any joy! I'll let you know how I get on!

Comment: I tried the other function and it had the same results. Thanks for the idea anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to figure it out. I had to remove the 'streetViewAvailable' variable and instead put a function inside the streetviewstatus if statement. Here's what it ended up looking like.

```
var WINDOW_HTML = '<div style="width: 200px; overflow: hidden; word-wrap:break-word;"><p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($title); ?><br /><?php echo htmlspecialchars($locationDetails); ?></p></div>';
    var map = '';
    var myLatlng;                     

    function initialize() {                 
        myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo htmlspecialchars($lat.','.$lon); ?>);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('themap'), mapOptions);


        /* Resize Fix for tabs */
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'resize', function() {
            this.setZoom(13);
            this.setCenter(myLatlng);
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: WINDOW_HTML
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map
            });            
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });                
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        }); 

        /* Check Streetview is available */
        var streetViewService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
        var STREETVIEW_MAX_DISTANCE = 50;

        streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(myLatlng, STREETVIEW_MAX_DISTANCE, function (streetViewPanoramaData, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {                   
                function svcheck() {                                                       
                    var panoramaOptions = {
                        position: myLatlng,
                        pov: {
                          heading: 34,
                          pitch: 10
                        },
                        visible:true
                    }
                    var panorama = new  google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'),panoramaOptions);                    
                    map.setStreetView(panorama); 

                    // Tab fix for streetview refresh  
                    $('#svTab').on('shown', function (e) {
                        $('#pano').show();                   
                        panorama.setVisible(true);                              
                    });
                }
                svcheck();
            } else {
                /* Street view is unavailable - HIDE THE TAB! */
                $('#svTab').hide(); 
            }
        });

    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```