# Finding businesses with Google Virtual Tour panoramas

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am wondering if it's possible in any way to get a list of businesses that have done a Google Virtual Tour (basically a Street View, for businesses) by querying in Google Maps API.

I was hoping that perhaps the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_responses) might contain this information in a response, but no dice. This is kind of visible in an everyday map (see [Hotel Boulderado](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Hotel+Boulderado/@40.0194304,-105.2792178,3585m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x6752f962392942f8!6m1!1e1)) but I don't think the information is included in any kind of query I can do.

I also saw a few questions dealing with [finding a Street View](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview) by a specific LatLng - I'm looking for a more general, area-based search.

Any ideas or things I missed?

Answer (score 0):

**I was hoping that perhaps the Places Library might contain this information in a response**

Places API can provide you a "list of businesses" in an area by trying to filter it up with specific Place Types. You are, however, limited to the constants the API provides. If you're using `PlacesService`, you can use `nearbysearch` which I think is more appropriate to your case.

**I also saw a few questions dealing with finding a Street View by a specific LatLng - I'm looking for a more general, area-based search.**

I'm not sure what you mean by "area-based search", but Street View on a specific LatLng can be tricky since its only available on some areas. The [Explore StreetView](https://www.google.com/maps/streetview/explore/) site highlights what countries currently have data (zooming in suggests that it doesn't necessarily captured the whole country; mostly are road routes, etc.)

A [StackOverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675032/how-to-check-if-google-street-view-available-and-display-message) indicates a way to handle if StreetView is available or not.

Hopefully the answer raised some clarifications in your end.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any part of any API that actually lists if StreetView is available. It's possible to send a latlng and get back a result or not, but no way to programmatically check to see if business listings have a Virtual Tour attached. Thanks though.