# Check if google streetview location exists or not to hide a view

Tags: android, google-maps, google-street-view

I am currently working on an android application which requires me to use street view in my app. I have made a StreetViewActivity to show the street view. But before that activity, I have another activity called Location Activity that has a button that takes the user to the StreetViewActivity. Now my question is how can I check if the latitude and longitude that is provided don't have a streetview then it should hide the button that would prevent the user from going to the StreetViewActivity? I can check if the lat lng exists in my StreetViewActivity but I need to check in the previous activity.

What I have done so far in My StreetViewActivity:

```
LOCATION = new LatLng(Latitude, Longitude);
    SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment streetViewPanoramaFragment =
            (SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment)
                    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.streetviewpanorama);
    streetViewPanoramaFragment.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(
            new OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(final StreetViewPanorama panorama) {

                    if (savedInstanceState == null) {

                        panorama.setPosition(LOCATION);
                        panorama.setOnStreetViewPanoramaChangeListener(new StreetViewPanorama.OnStreetViewPanoramaChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onStreetViewPanoramaChange(StreetViewPanoramaLocation loc) {
                                if (loc != null && loc.links != null) {
                                    //panorama.setPosition(LOCATION);
                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(PropertyStreetViewActivity.this, "No Street View Available For This Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .show();
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
            });
```

And a Screenshot of my LocationActivity:
[image: Map With StreetView Button]

Answer (score 0):

How to check if latitude and longitude that is provided don't have a streetview was already solved in [How to check if Google Street View available and display message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675032/how-to-check-if-google-street-view-available-and-display-message)

By default, [Street View](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewMapUsage) is enabled on a map and a Street View Pegman control appears integrated within the navigation (zoom and pan) controls. You may hide this control within the map's MapOptions by setting streetViewControl to false.

```
streetViewControl: false
```

Comment: This is for android BTW.

Comment: For Android, [Google Maps Android API - Customize the user-controlled functionality](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/streetview#customize_the_user-controlled_functionality) can help. :)