# Check if a location has Panoramic View

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, google-street-view

I am building an App using Xamarin in Visual Studio 2017.
In my App, I'm using Google Panoramic View.

The App gets a location from the user and displays the Panoramic View. 

My problem is that not every location has a Panoramic View.
What I'm asking is: there's a way to identify whether a Panoramic View is available for a specific location.

Comment: show some code or illustrate your problem better so you can get help

Comment: i have built the street view part using the code in this link. https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-immersive-panoramic-google-maps/

Comment: Does anyone have a solution

Comment: You could refer to: [How to check if Google Street View available and display message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675032/how-to-check-if-google-street-view-available-and-display-message)

Answer (score 0):

To identify whether a Panoramic View  is available for a specific location.

for example, lets assume that you have this parameters to request StreetView Image or Panorama:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x800&location=-6.2898696,106.7709091 &fov=90&heading=90&pitch=0 &key=[YOUR_API_KEY]

Paste to your browser for test and you will get an Image of Streetview.

A Street View image metadata request is an HTTP URL of the following form:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview/metadata?parameters

so you have to little bit edit your parameters above to:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview/metadata?size=400x800&location=-6.2898696,106.7709091 &fov=90&heading=90&pitch=0 &key=[YOUR_API_KEY]

Paste it again to your browser then you will get this response:

{
   "copyright" : "© Google, Inc.",
   "date" : "2017-09",
   "location" : {
      "lat" : -6.289908952742929,
      "lng" : 106.7709156700797
   },
   "pano_id" : "6Q2SZz9GDC7X3_EWjjs96g",
   "status" : "OK"
}

Don't forget to replace [YOUR_API_KEY] with yours.